# Extract and update DataFrame column names

Tags: python, pandas

Reading data into DataFrame, expect certain column names but often they are mixed with a random string either before or after the name. There are also other columns and the column order is not guaranteed. I want to rename the applicable columns to the correct names.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(4, 5),
    columns=['betarandstr1.823491', 'alpha randstr123', 'other', 'delta', 'randstr-1.281999 gamma']
    )

keys = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta'] # expected names
```

I can extract the desired name for each column.

```
>>> df.columns.str.extract('(%s)' % '|'.join(keys))

       0
0   beta
1  alpha
2    NaN
3  delta
4  gamma
```

My question is how to update the names, but if NaN to keep the original name. So the desired result in this case `'other'` is retained instead of NaN.

```
>>> df.columns
         
Index(['beta', 'alpha', 'other', 'delta', 'gamma'],
      dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your approach, you can use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html?highlight=combine_first#pandas.DataFrame.combine_first) :

```
df.columns = (
    df.columns.str.extract('(%s)' % '|'.join(keys))
        .combine_first(df.columns.to_frame(index=False))[0]
)
```

Another variant with [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) :

```
df.columns = (
    df.columns.str.extract('(%s)' % '|'.join(keys))[0]
        .fillna(df.columns.to_series().reset_index(drop=True))
)
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)

   beta  alpha  other  delta  gamma
0  1.30   0.21  -1.58   0.91   0.85
1  0.88   0.18  -0.13  -0.18   0.37
2  2.43  -0.23  -1.20  -0.44   0.35
3  0.41  -0.51   0.20   0.58   0.08
```